# SQL Update (simple??)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have 2 tables

Table `Customers`:

```
id,
CustomerName
```

Table `CustomerMapping`

```
ID
WrongName,
CorrectedName
```

What I want to do is :

> *Update my TableCustomers.CustomerName with the TableCustomerMapping.CorrectName if TableCustomers.CustomerName = TableCustomerMapping.WrongName*

I tried this update statement but it is taking way too long, (6+ minutes) before I give up and cancel the query. I should not be taking that long to update 1000 rows.

Here is the Update statement I was trying, am I missing something?

```
UPDATE i
SET i.CustomerJob = c.CorrectedName
FROM dbo.TableCustomers i
LEFT JOIN dbo.CustomerMapping c ON (i.CustomerJob = c.WrongName);
GO
```

Comment: What happens if you do a select i.CustomerJob, C.QBName FROM dbo.TableCustomers i
    left JOIN dbo.CustomerMapping c
    ON (i.CustomerJob = c.MOAName)? Do you get 1000 rows, or more?

Comment: If you only want to update where the customer name is equal to the wrong name, why not try an inner join on where those two are equal instead of grabbing everything from the Customers table with a left join. Not sure how much it will improve performance but it's worth a shot

Comment: Are those two tables related by ID?

Comment: Jason, I did that and I get 1000 rows.

Comment: They are not related by id, the only way currently to relate them would be to match based on CustomerName column with the WrongName column in the other table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those two tables related by *`c.CustomerName = m.WrongName`*.

Also *note*, *`there could be more than one person with same wrong name & correct name`*. Given the situation (*`not related by IDs`*) I think following (*`INNER JOIN or JOIN`*) will do the job;

```
--Do this select first for safety
select c.CustomerName, m.CorrectedName
from TableCustomers c join TableCustomerMapping m on c.CustomerName = m.WrongName

--Update if okay
update c
set c.CustomerName = m.CorrectedName
from TableCustomers c join TableCustomerMapping m on c.CustomerName = m.WrongName
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't do a `LEFT JOIN`... if you do that, you will be updating every record in the `Customers` table, and will set all the unmatched records to `NULL`... instead, do an `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.CustomerName = cm.CorrectedName
FROM dbo.Customers c
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerMapping cm ON (c.CustomerName = cm.WrongName);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are comparing strings. It's likely your string column has no indexes so for every row in Table 'TableCustomers' the query has to do a table scan on 'CustomerMapping'. You will need to add an index on CustomerMapping on the WrongName field in order for the query optimizer to avoid a table scan and find the data needed without killing performance. So create an index (which if your data set is super large might take some time). I am unsure but you might be able to do a subquery as well and Sort the data by WrongName to aid the query... but the best bet is an index.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add a foreign key to TableCustomerMapping

```
**TableCustomerMapping**
___________________
ID,
fkCustomerID,
WrongName,
CorrectedName
```

Then use that to join the 2 tables together and you will update just the 1 record

```
UPDATE i
SET i.CustomerJob = c.QBName
FROM dbo.TableCustomers i
LEFT JOIN dbo.CustomerMapping c ON (i.ID= c.fkCustomerID);
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to do.
Try this example:

```
UPDATE TABLEA
 SET b = TABLEB.b1,
     c = TABLEB.c1,
     d = TABLEB.d1
 FROM TABLEA, TABLEB
 WHERE TABLEA.a = TABLEB.a1
 AND TABLEB.e1 > 40
 GO
```

I hope you work